# which IP to use to connect to two different computers using telnet C

Tags: c, telnet

I have two laptops, both running Ubuntu.

I want to write a chat server in C, which can talk to my other laptop and receive messages back from it.

I know that when the client and server programs are both in a single machine, I can use local host (127.0.0.1) and make them talk using telnet but what about connecting two different computers (which are on the same network)? Which IP and port should I use for them?

Comment: The IP address of the respective computer.

Comment: Do you mean the client's or the server's?

Comment: For computer A to connect to computer B, A needs to use B’s IP address.

Comment: and for B to connect to A it needs A's IP right?\

Comment: Yes. (This comment was too short.)

Comment: Do they have to use the same port (anything more than port number 1024)?

Comment: If you’re writing the program you can use whatever port you want (but avoid [the ones taken by others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)).

Comment: I think you need to back up and work on understanding the basics.  You pick the port, avoid the well known ones you pick the protocol, can use some known ones if it helps.  If you want to call me you would call my phone number not yours.  If I wanted to call you I would call your phone number not my own.  That should be pretty obvious.  Before writing any code use tools like ping, ssh, etc to get a feel for this.  also read up on the berkley sockets library, when someone connects you get a return address generally depends on protocol, just like caller id if someone calls you...

Comment: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html) or for a shorter explanation [Socket Programming Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/index.htm)

Answer (score -1):

A is the Server with IP[A] address (ex: 192.168.1.2)
B is the Client with IP[B] address

So on your chat Server on A at some point in the code you will open a port, you will specify a port number to open. If the number of the port is X then on the client you will connect to IP[A]:X

To give you an example with X=4444, you will open a connection like: 192.168.1.2:4444

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

Basically all that you need to make sure as far as a port goes is that the port is not already in use by another service. There is a number a ways to do this, but I suggest you start by looking at [commonly used ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

As far as IP goes, you are going to want to determine if you want to use the public or private IP of the machines that you are attempting to connect. If you are using the public IPs you will probably have to set up [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) in some capacity. If you are just connecting two private ips (i.e. the one the same network) then you don't need to port forward.

Ultimately, this issue is highly specific to you use case and we would need more information to answer it for your exact case.